# Is it possible to simplify these With statements?

Tags: excel, vba

new to VBA, but I feel like this could be simplified, just not sure how since I'm still learning.

I was wondering if it's possible to simplify these With statements:

```
With outputSheet.Range("C5:C" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    .Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A5,'" & dataSheet.Name & "'!C:E,3,0)"
    .Value = .Value
End With

With outputSheet.Range("E5:E" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    .Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A5,'" & dataSheet.Name & "'!C:G,5,0)"
    .Value = .Value
End With

With outputSheet.Range("F5:F" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    .Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A5,'" & dataSheet.Name & "'!C:H,6,0)"
    .Value = .Value
End With
```

I was thinking of dropping the .Range down, but it gives an "invalid use of property error", was wondering if someone could explain why it gives an error. Like so:

```
With outputSheet
    .Range ("C5:C" & .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    .Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A5,'" & dataSheet.Name & "'!C:E,3,0)"
    .Range ("E5:E" & .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    .Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A5,'" & dataSheet.Name & "'!C:G,5,0)"
    .Value = .Value
End With
```

Thanks for any help/feedback!

Comment: `With [object]` defines an object.  ----> `.Row` returns a row number. A row number has no properties. Therefore, speaking of its *Formula* or *Value* property results in an error.

Comment: True, but OP is not doing that, at least in the code I can see.

Comment: Variatus help create the original With statement, I have to do it to multiple columns now. Was wondering if theres a way to simplify all the With statements, not quite sure how to go about doing that.

Answer (score 2):

The reason

```vb
With outputSheet
    .Range ("C5:C" & .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    .Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A5,'" & dataSheet.Name & "'!C:E,3,0)"
    .Range ("E5:E" & .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    .Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A5,'" & dataSheet.Name & "'!C:G,5,0)"
    .Value = .Value
End With
```

throws an error is that you are referencing a Range, but not doing anything with it.  Also, a Worksheet doesn't have a `Values` property

This can be fixed as

```
With outputSheet
    With .Range("C5:C" & .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        .Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A5,'" & dataSheet.Name & "'!C:E,3,0)"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
    With .Range("E5:E" & .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        .Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A5,'" & dataSheet.Name & "'!C:G,5,0)"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End With
```

Comment: nicely explained

Answer (score 0):

Using the `With` statement is relatively easy. Put the object you mean to work with in the opening statement and then replace every repetition of that object in the code before `End With` with a leading period. Instead of

```
lastRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, 1).End.xlUp).Row
' you can say
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
End With
```

However, your code suffers from another ailment. You try to address ranges of cells as `Range`. Then you become confused with the syntax. It's easier if you make it a rule to address single cells as members of the `Cells` collection (Syntax: `Cells([Row], [Column]`) and only ranges of several cells by the range's names. Then, bear in mind that a range, though named and addressed by its name ("A1:D4" is a name because it's presented as a string), is defined by its first and last cells. Since a cell is defined by 2 numbers, row and column, you can also define a range without using any string expressions, and that makes programming a whole lot easier.

The other problem with your code is the intended use of VLOOKUP to first retrieve a value and then be replaced by the value it retrieved. Why not simply retrieve the value and write that to the cell. The lookup formula should never come to the cell. But if you think of using that method you wouldn't use it 3 times. Instead, you would find the row where your data come from and pick 3 values from that row. That's what the code below does.

```
Sub Snippet()
    ' 216

    Dim Rng     As Range            ' Lookup range in dataSheet
    Dim Fnd     As Range            ' Cell where match was found
    Dim R       As Long             ' Loop counter: rows
    Dim LookUp  As Variant          ' return of VLOOKUP
    
    Set Rng = dataSheet.Columns("C:C")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    With outputSheet
        ' Observe that both the 'Cells' and 'Rows.Count' are on
        ' the sheet specified by the 'With' statement.
        ' Therefore both require the leading period.
        For R = 5 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            Set Fnd = Rng.Find(.Cells(R, "A").Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
            If Not Fnd Is Nothing Then
                .Cells(R, "C").Value = dataSheet.Cells(Fnd.Row, "E").Value
                .Cells(R, "E").Value = dataSheet.Cells(Fnd.Row, "G").Value
                .Cells(R, "F").Value = dataSheet.Cells(Fnd.Row, "H").Value
            End If
        Next R
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I'm not sure of collecting the correct values from the *dataSheet* and assigning them to the correct cells on the *outputSheet*. However, because of the simplified syntax I use for addressing cells you will be able to make any necessary adjustments in a jiffy.

I just see that you have more than 3 values to pick. You can easily expand my system. However, consider creating a loop instead of 10 almost identical lines for transferring the data.

Answer (score -1):

Does this look any "cleaner"? I  am assuming that the .Value =.Value statement was intended to replace formulas with values.

```
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim r As Range

lastRow = outputSheet.Columns(1).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set r = outputSheet.Range("C5:C" & lastRow)
r.Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A5,'" & dataSheet.Name & "'!C:E,3,0)"
r.Copy
r.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Set r = outputSheet.Range("E5:E" & lastRowRow)
r.Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A5,'" & dataSheet.Name & "'!C:G,5,0)"
r.Copy
r.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Set r = outputSheet.Range("F5:F" & lastRowRow)
r.Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A5,'" & dataSheet.Name & "'!C:H,6,0)"
r.Copy
r.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Comment: Understood - when I tried excel didn't like it either. Is there a way to clean multiple With statements?

Comment: I only showed 3 With statements, but I have 10 in total reference each column where I'm doing a vlookup. I guess theres no way to shorten the code but achieve the same results? Seems redundant to have 10 With statements.